# Android charting library with inbuilt support to plot graph for days, weeks, months and years break down from input data

Tags: android, plot, charts, lib

Is there any charting library in Android that has built-in support to plot graph for days, weeks, months and years break down of input data.

How to develop a graph which looks like this ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like no library has built-in support to show data grouped by day, week, month and year, etc. So we are doing it ourselves.